# Sort List of arrays according to specific array elements

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have a `List` of arrays where the fifth element of each array (`array[4]`) is of type `Date` and the fourth element of each array (`array[3]`) is of type `String`. I am trying to sort the `List` according to the date, then the string. I tried it using `Collections.sort()` with a custom `Comparator`, but without success:

```
 List <Object[]> execute(List <Object[]> resultList){   

            Collections.sort(resultList, new Comparator<Object[]>() {
                public int compare(Object[] array, Object[] otherArray) {
                    int dateComparison = array[4].compareTo(otherArray[4]);
                     return dateComparison == 0 ? array[3].compareTo(otherArray[3]) : dateComparison;
                }
            });

    return resultList;
    }
```

**Input**

```
02.02.2017 10:00   B
02.02.2017 09:00   A
01.02.2017 18:00   AC
01.02.2017 16:00   AB
02.02.2017 11:00   C
01.02.2017 13:00   AA
02.02.2017 12:00   D
01.02.2017 21:00   AD
```

**The output should looks like-->**

```
01.02.2017 13:00   AA
01.02.2017 16:00   AB
01.02.2017 18:00   AC
01.02.2017 21:00   AD
02.02.2017 09:00   A
02.02.2017 10:00   B
02.02.2017 11:00   C
02.02.2017 12:00   D
```

**Edit1**

I have implemented a simple example:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


public class Comperable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            List<Object[]> resultList = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
            Object[] array1 = { dateFormat.parse("2017-02-25 16:10:00.0"), "C" };
            Object[] array2 = { dateFormat.parse("2017-02-20 16:50:00.0"), "CB" };
            Object[] array3 = { dateFormat.parse("2017-02-19 19:42:00.0"), "AB" };
            Object[] array4 = { dateFormat.parse("2017-02-20 19:46:00.0"), "BA" };
            Object[] array5 = { dateFormat.parse("2017-02-16 19:33:58.0"), "ZC" };
            Object[] array6 = { dateFormat.parse("2017-02-16 19:45:10.0"), "A" };
            Object[] array7 = { dateFormat.parse("2017-02-16 20:47:48.0"), "B" };
            resultList.add(array1);
            resultList.add(array2);
            resultList.add(array3);
            resultList.add(array4);
            resultList.add(array5);
            resultList.add(array6);
            resultList.add(array7);
            Collections.sort(resultList, new Comparator<Object[]>() {

                public int compare(Object[] array, Object[] otherArray) {
                    int dateComparison = (((Date) array[0]).compareTo((Date) otherArray[0]));
                    return dateComparison == 0 ? ((String) array[1]).compareTo((String) otherArray[1]) : dateComparison;
                }
            });

            for (int i = 0; i <= resultList.size() - 1; i++) {
                Object[] row = resultList.get(i);
                System.out.println("Date: " + row[0] + "  name: " + row[1]);

            }

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: well, given your code, you are comparing with array[4] and _then_ array[3]

Comment: also, what do you expect `array[4].compareTo(otherArray[4])` to do? what is the comparison between those 2 `Object` supposed to be?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Perhaps including a desired input and output would help

Comment: Great! What is the input?

Comment: What's your current output ?

Comment: Let me know if my edits are acceptable. I tried to make the question easier to understand based on the code.

Comment: But then you clobbered my edit, so nevermind.

Comment: Also, aren't you getting a compilation error that you aren't telling us about? "Without success" means nothing if you don't tell us what the specific problem is.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I am not getting compilation error . I am running the code as Groovy script.

Comment: That does not remove the need to tell us what "without success" means. How do you know it's failing?

Comment: It is failing because when  printing the resultList after sorting .  I can see that the List is sorted after array[4] date but not after array[3] name of the driver.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Please would you take a look at my edit part. It still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing is that you need to cast the `Object` type to `Date` type and invoke `compareTo` method.

(1) Cast the type of `array[4]` and `otherArray[4]` to Date type and then call `compareTo`

(2) Also, cast the type of `array[3]` and `otherArray[3]` to `String` type and then call `compareTo`

You can refer the below code with inline comments:

```
Collections.sort(resultList, new Comparator<Object[]>() {
     public int compare(Object[] array, Object[] otherArray) {

     //do the Date comparison by casting Object to Date
     int dateComparison = (((Date)array[4]).compareTo((Date)otherArray[4]));

      //Now, do the String comparison by casting Object to String
     return dateComparison == 0 ? 
             ((String)array[3]).compareTo((String)otherArray[3]) : dateComparison;
      }
 });
```

> I want to sort the list after the date and then after the String since
>   I want to print the data in the jasper report. In my case I can not
>   manage the sorting in the database.

**The above code exactly does the same**, it compares the Date objects first and if they are equal then it will compare the strings.

Comment: Java uses runtime polymorphism. The cast is unnecessary.

Comment: If you don't apply cast, how do you call `compareTo` method on `java.lang.Object`?

Comment: Good call. You just need to cast to `Comparable` or anything that implements it. Vote flipped.

Comment: @javaguy: It being being sorted after the date array[4] but not after the array[3] String?

Comment: You can look now, compares String first and then date

Comment: Would you mind mentioning that casting to `Comparable` would work too?

Comment: @javaguy: but I want to sort the list after the date and then after the String since I want to print the data in the jasper report. In my case I can not manage the sorting in the database.

Comment: @to get the date sorted after the day of the date i added the following: array[4].getDate()